# supervised learning aiming precision on a certain interval of y

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, supervised-learning

I want to build a model that $X$ explains $y$. More specifically, I am mainly interested in a certain interval of $y \in (a, b)$, such that whenever the model predicts $\hat{y} \in (a,b)$, I want the prediction to be very precise (that real value is also in the interval). However, if the predicted value is not in $(a,b)$, it is less important whether it is close to the real value.

It is similar to the classification problem where precision is much more important than recall rate.

My current idea is to use weighted loss, which gives a twice weight on $\hat{y}_i \in (a,b)$ and additionally add $\sum_i I(\hat{y}_i \notin (a,b))$ as a penalizing term to prevent model adapting on safer choice (keep predicting $\hat{y} \notin (a,b)$)

Is there any model/methodology that would be suitable for the problem? Any references, rough ideas, or whatever would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The way you wrote your first paragraph, it sounds like the "importance" hangs only on the prediction $\hat{y}$, not on the corresponding actual $y$. So if the model believes but is not completely certain that $y\in(a,b)$, e.g., $\hat{P}(y\in(a,b))=0.8$, it would nevertheless be incentivized to predict some $\hat{y}\not\in(a,b)$ - even if such a $y$ *does* have an 80% probability of being in $(a,b)$. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for your comment. Yes, the model would be incentivized to predict $\hat{y} \notin (a,b)$. That is what I meant by "model adapting on safer choice" in 3rd paragraph.

Comment: I was thinking of the weighted loss part from such intuition: MSE loss is connected with negative log-likelihood of normal dist (by assuming gaussian noise). As such, training data over the MSE loss penalizes the whole domain of data to learn a general representation.

So, I was roughly thinking that weighted loss on a certain interval (which I guess corresponds to Gaussian mixture distribution) will help learn the underlying representation of data associated with high precision on the certain interval.